# using cas server with mongodb backend

Tags: mongodb, tomcat7, maven, cas

I 'm new to setting up cas(Central Authentication Service) server. I couldn't find any guides to setup mongodb as backend for CAS server. Is there an adapter to connect CAS and mongodb. BTW, we don't want to use LDAP. I have installed necessary packages in ubuntu(jdk,tomcat,maven2,) but wasn't sure how to edit pom.xml to work with mongodb. Please advice...

Answer (score 0):

No official backend exists for MongoDB as a CAS datasource.

But, [as CAS is able to interact with a database through JDBC](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Using+JDBC+for+Authentication) and there is a JDBC driver for MongoDB, you may be able to use MongoDB as datasource.